# (th:text) How concat a Message (i18n) expressions with other text

Tags: thymeleaf

I am working with:

- `Thymeleaf` 3.0.9.RELEASE
- `Spring Framework`

About `i18n` the following works fine (within any `html` component):

```
th:text="#{person.name.label}"
```

The `person.name.label` key exists within a `.properties` file and according with a `Locale` value, for example `Name` is printed.

I need print now instead `Name:`. Observe the `:`, it for example to be used for a `<label>`

If I try:

```
th:text="#{person.name.label}:"
```

I get

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: 
Could not parse as expression: "#{persona.name.label}:"
```

If I try

```
th:text="#{person.name.label:}"
```

The `??persona.name.label:_en_US??` is printed instead.

I don't want add `:` directly within the `.properties` file because I want use `person.name.label` in a `<th>` within the `<thead>`, thus there is not necessary print `:`

How is the correct approach?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Standard syntax for appending text.](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appending-texts)

```
th:text="#{person.name.label} + ':'"
```

[Or, you may be interested in literal substitution.](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions)

```
th:text="|#{person.name.label}:|"
```

[You can also accomplish these kinds of expressions with inlining.](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining)  This is enabled by default in Thymeleaf 3, and the expressions look like this.

```
<span>[[#{person.name.label}]]:</span>
```

In Thymeleaf 2, you have to enable this feature by adding `th:inline`, like this:

```
<span th:inline="text">[[#{person.name.label}]]:</span>
```

Comment: I am using the second approach because I am working through `th:text` and is less verbose than the first option. Furthemore is the unique that works. Consider in add a link about your source of these three approaches, specially where is explained about the `(depending on your thymeleaf version and inline settings)` sentence